# Hover in background doesn't work with position absolute over it

Tags: html, css, hover, css-position, absolute

I've a container on which I use an hover state.
Everytime I hover over it, the background changes to a different color.

In addition I use a navigation which I display with postion: absolute over the container. Everytime I hover over the navigation, the background change doesn't work because I'm not over the container in the background.

Is there any workaround for that?

My code (hover over the 1):

```css
.wrapper {position: relative;}
.container {background: red; width: 100%; height:200px;}
.container:hover {background: blue;}
.nav {position:absolute; top:50%;margin: 0 auto; width:100%; text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
  
  </div>
  <div  class="nav">
    <a href="#">1</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is hard to understand what you want here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the navigation bar inside the container:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div  class="nav">
            <a href="#">1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's `position: absolute` so inside or outside isn't an issue.

---

Or use javascript:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container" onmouseover="change()" onmouseout="changeBack()">

    </div>
    <div  class="nav" onmouseover="change()">
        <a href="#">1</a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    window.change = function() {
        console.log("hello");
        document.getElementsByClassName("container")[1].style.background = "blue";
    }

    window.changeBack = function() {
        console.log("hello");
        document.getElementsByClassName("container")[1].style.background = "red";
    }
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3h1orsmu/1/

Comment: unfortunately, that is not possible in the project :-(

Comment: Edited answer to include javascript solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use the wrapper's hover state, but target the container:

```
.wrapper:hover .container{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible in the project because there are more containers in the wrapper should not be affected. And there is no way to select one :-(

Comment: Can you add a new class to the element so that it would only affect the one instance. Then just target that with the code above. (would be clear of  what "Can and can't be done" - As you have to answers which do solve the problem.)